# depth camera min max range adjustment

Tags: gazebo-camera

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How can I adjust the minimum and maximum range provided by the depth cameras? Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/105/depth-camera-min-max-range-adjustment/) by [Dubya](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/13/dubya/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can specify the near and far clip planes for a camera, see SDF documentation: http://gazebosim.org/sdf/1.3.html#clip

Try that out and see if it works for you.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0